# Problem Clearing TextBox in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, onclick

I am new to this, but I am trying to clear whatever content is in a text box. The code I have in the body section is as follows:

```
<body>

<FORM NAME = "frmOne" method=POST>

 Name: <INPUT TYPE=text NAME=name onFocus="this.form.name.value=''" /><br />

 <input type="button" value="Click To Clear" onClick="clearForm(this.form)">


 </FORM>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT">

function clearForm(form){

form.name.value = "";

</SCRIPT>

</body>
```

Problem is, clicking the button does nothing and anything in the Name box remains there! Can anyone suggest why? I am probably making a very basic mistake.

Thanks,

Stuart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have a syntax error, you are missing a  `}`. It should be:

```
function clearForm(form){
    form.name.value = "";
} // <- you have to close the function
```

[Then it works.](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/kYs9Q/)

Tools like Chrome developer tools or Firebug for Firefox help you to detect such errors. For example, your code results in the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: Great thank you, I will need to look into getting an editor that indicates syntax errors because there will be a lot more in the future!

Comment: @Stumf: That is a good idea :) Also tools such as [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or Google's [Closure Linter](http://code.google.com/closure/utilities/docs/linter_howto.html) are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using name, its good practise to use ids.

So for your input, use:

```
<INPUT TYPE=text NAME=name ID="myFormTextbox" onFocus="this.value=''" /><br />
```

And for your js:

```
function clearForm(form) {
    document.getElementById("myFormTextbox").value = "";
}
```